# How can I share a NextAuth useSession() call across multiple components

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I have a web page displaying multiple server components. Each component has a link that should be displayed conditionally depending on login status, to it checks the session client side. This is a static page, so I don't want to use the server session.

Each component is currently calling `useSession()` individually leading to many redundant calls.

Is there a way I can share a single `useSession()` call on the client across multiple components?

I'd like to avoid this:

[image]